# Owl Carousel for rails - error raised by some options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, owl-carousel

i have a rails project which uses the owl carousel gem.
Everything works, more or less, but some of the carousel options raise a puzzling error.

For example: this works beautifully.

```
owl.owlCarousel({
    navigation : false, 
    slideSpeed : 300,
    paginationSpeed : 400,

    singleItem:true
});
```

If i add the `mouseDrag` option, like this:

```
owl.owlCarousel({
   navigation : false, 
   slideSpeed : 300,
   paginationSpeed : 400,
   mouseDrag : false,
   singleItem:true
});
```

i get this:

```
 SyntaxError: [stdin]:16:15: unexpected :
```

at the line of the `mouseDrag` option in my CoffeeScript file.
Any ideas?

Edit: solved. Probably some invisible character was messing up the parsing of the script.

Comment: Can you show us how the compiled javascript looks like?

Comment: if i try to compile it i get the very same error:

  ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: [stdin]:16:15: unexpected :

(i compiled it using the script found here: http://scottwb.com/blog/2012/06/30/compile-a-single-coffeescript-file-from-your-rails-project)

Comment: Have you tried making the JSON objects go like `mouseDrag: false` rather than `mouseDrag : false` (Notice the space)

Comment: yes and there is no change (other options use the space before ":" and they just work).

Comment: Tried compiling using the script as well and i got something like this: https://gist.github.com/fyquah95/ffac58de7aad04ef88de . It works perfectly fine for me, are you sure the SyntaxError is from that particular line?
Another possibility you can try is using literal keys, i.e. : {"a": 123, "b": true}

Comment: I _literally_ copy-pasted your script and _it worked._
I'm starting to think that there could have been an invisible character typed in my code which messed up the parser, since i'm working using three different platforms and three different text editors.

Comment: I'll add an answer just to make things clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably added some invalid charcaters before the colon.

Copying and pasting your script (here is a gist: https://gist.github.com/fyquah95/ffac58de7aad04ef88de) worked. The best way is to just *retype* the script and it should work.